# GUI using JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

I created a project using JOptionpane but I need to convert it into a JFrame using windowbuilder. I have never used windowbuilder before so I am unsure how to convert my code. When comparing my list I am using numbers 525616 for both lists. When I run the code I am getting dialog boxes but I need something more appealing. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     // Enter values for list1
      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter list1: ");
    int size1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
    int[] list1 = new int[size1];

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) 
      list1[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);

    // Enter values for list2
    String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter list2: ");
    int size2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
    int[] list2 = new int[size2];


    for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) 
      list2[i] = Integer.parseInt(input2);

    if (equals(list1, list2)) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Two lists are strictly identical");
    }
    else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Two lists are not strictly identical");
    }
  }

    public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
    if (list1.length != list2.length)
      return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) 
      if (list1[i] != list2[i])
        return false;

    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: *"..but I need something more appealing."*  But we need a specific question.  If your question is *"how to convert my code?"* or *"how to use WindowBuilder?"*, then they will be 'too broad' for SO.  What is your question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson could you guide me to a place where I could learn more about WindowBuilder? I have never used it before and I just need to create a GUI using this program. I have only ever created a GUI through Eclipse. Thank you!

Comment: *"could you guide me to a place where I could learn more about WindowBuilder?"* If that 'place' is a search engine with search string WindowBuilder - yes, otherwise no.

Comment: @AndrewThompson cool. Thanks for all your awesome help!! I'm pretty sure I am familiar with using a search engine but its nice to come to a place where people can recommend better references than what a search engine can provide. It is helpful to weed out the bad sites from the good.

Comment: (shrugs)  I don't use GUI builders in general, Window Builder in particular, or Eclipse (much).  So I'm confident that Google can provide better links than ***I*** can.  I suggest you start with docs. on the Eclipse site, or the site of whoever delivers/supplies the Window Builder tool.  'Straight from the horses mouth' has to be better than trying to get information from users who *think* they know how to use it.

Comment: Note also there is another close reason that comes down to 'requesting links to offsite resources'.  So, right there we have a *2nd reason* for closing this question.  (I have already voted to close as 'too broad', so cannot vote again.)